# iPhone MapKit: select location (coordinates) manually by touching MKMapView

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkmapview

I would like to offer the user the possibility to (manually) select lat. and long. coordinates by touching a `MKMapView`. How can I achieve that?

I've seen that the `MKMapView` delegate offers the method `convertPoint:toCoordinateFromView:` . I think, that could be a good starting, but I don't know how to create a point from a touch action.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `UITouch` object (see [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) has the API:

```
- (CGPoint)locationInView:(UIView *)view
```

Then use the `MKMapView` API you identified.

Answer (score 10):

`vwMap` is the name of `MKMapview` object:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(foundTap:)]; 
tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1; 
[vwMap addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];



-(IBAction)foundTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:vwMap];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D tapPoint = [vwMap convertPoint:point toCoordinateFromView:vwMap];

    MKPointAnnotation *point1 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init]; 
    point1.coordinate = tapPoint;

    [vwMap addAnnotation:point1];
}
```